# PHP Function as a Function's Default Parameter

Tags: php, arguments

I was wondering if there is a simpler way that I can use a php inbuilt function as the default value for a function.

Here's my current code:

```
function custom_date($format = 'm-d-Y', $time = null)
{
    if($format == "d-m-Y") {
        // do something with $time
    }
    return date($format, $time);
}
```

I want to use `time()` as a default argument for `$time` instead of `null`, but it will not let me. I know I can pass `time()` as a 2nd argument to `custom_date` everywhere its called, but it's used at many places without 2nd argument and changing it would be a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just force `$time` to be equal to `time()` when there has been no value passed to the function.

```
function custom_date($format = 'm-d-Y', $time = null)
{
    $time = (null == $time) ? time() : $time;
    if($format == "d-m-Y") {
        // do something with $time
    }
    return date($format, $time);
 }
```

Comment: I believe this is what OP really wanted. Give it a default of **null**, and check if it's null in the function.

Comment: Just FYI, > PHP 5.3 You can use `$time = $time ?: time();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function custom_date($format = 'm-d-Y', $func = 'time') {
if (function_exists($func)) {
    if ($format == "d-m-Y") {
        // do something with $time
    }
    return date($format, $func());
}elseif(is_numeric($func)){
    //timestamp logic
}}
```

Comment: this won't work either as in some cases, I am passing $time argument with timestamp value, and `call_user_func(timestamp)` would fail

Comment: @dhavald I just made a few changes to the above code. Hope that helps